# How can I force wordpress backend to a specific language using qTranslate?

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I am using qTranslate in wordpress and have enabled the option to choose language automatically depending the browser language.

This works great but I don't like to have the wordpress backend translated. How do I turn it off only for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the flag of the country you want on the sidebar, the whole ui changes. This is not permanent but its ok :)